# Где исполнять обращение java к js в webview?

Tags: java, android, webview

Есть приложение для андроида через webview,
требуется раз в 5 секунд обращаться из activity в javascript внутри webview.

подскажите пожалуйста или дайте наводку куда поместить

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:wvinit('some_dataq')");
```

в onPageFinished работает разово, если запустить цикл, то ui ждет пока цикл отработает и только после этого показывает интерфейс.

в onStart приложение просто закрывается

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 
        /*// globally
        TextView crds = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.crds);
 
        //in your OnCreate() method123
        crds.setText("CUR LAT,LON");*/
 
 
        String mfr = Build.MANUFACTURER;
        String mdl = Build.MODEL;
        String fngr = Build.FINGERPRINT;
        String aid = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
 
        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(getFilesDir().getPath());
 
        webView.loadUrl("http://someurl.ru/app.php?mfr="+mfr+"&mdl="+mdl+"&fngr="+fngr+"&aid="+aid);
 
 
        WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
                //view.loadUrl("about:blank");
                view.loadData("<center><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><b>Сервер не доступен!</b><br>Проверьте подключение к интернету</center>", "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
            }
 
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
 
 
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                return true;
            }
 
            /*
            public void on(){
                Integer i = 0;
                WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
 
                        if (webView != null) {
                            webView.loadUrl("javascript:wvinit('some_data" + i + "')");
                        }
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }*/
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
 
            }
        };
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
        
/*TimerTask hourlyTask = new TimerTask () {
            @Override
            public void run ()
            {
                //WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:wvinit('some_dataq')");
            }
        };
 
        Timer timer = new Timer ();
        timer.schedule (hourlyTask, 0l, 3000);*/
    }
/*
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
 
        TimerTask hourlyTask = new TimerTask () {
            @Override
            public void run ()
            {
                WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:wvinit('some_dataq')");
            }
        };
 
        Timer timer = new Timer ();
        timer.schedule (hourlyTask, 0l, 3000);
    }
*/
 
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

решил, внизу mainactivity прописал handler и функцию, которую он будет исполнять

```
// Init
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        wvinit();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
    }
};
int i=0;
private void wvinit() {
    i++;
    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:wvinit('some_data"+i+"')");
}
```

и в блоке инициализации webview после завершения загрузки страницы запустил этот самый handler

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    //Start
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
}
```